# seraph: get db.query array values

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This code gives me... array? with columns and data, as i understand

console.log

```
{ columns: [ 'n.name' ],
  data: [ [ '(' ], [ 'node_name' ], [ ';' ], [ 'CREATE' ], [ ')' ] ] }
```

Code

```
function show() {
    var cypher = [
     'MATCH (n)-[r:CREATE_NODE_COMMAND]->(s)RETURN n.name'
     ].join('\n');
        db.queryRaw(cypher, {}, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
for (var key in result) {
}       
      console.log(result);
        })}
```

How to get clean data: keys like this (n.name;CREATE) ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a map of `key : value` in the cypher result set you can change the return statement to something like this...

```
return { name : n.name }
```

Comment: it gives me new array `[ [ { name: '(' } ],
  [ { name: 'node_name' } ],
  [ { name: ';' } ],
  [ { name: 'CREATE' } ],
  [ { name: ')' } ] ]` with `console.log(result[key]);`

Comment: you are getting an array of maps now.  The cypher will always return a collection of rows.  Your query is returning 5 rows so you have 5 rows in the collection.  What is your end goal? Do you want your query to return a single row?

Comment: i want to get clean name values without braces and quotes

Comment: you could get rid of the braces by doing something like this, `return 'n.name : ' + n.name`, but i can't think of how you will remove the quotes

Comment: thank you, it's working on the localhost:7474, however the seraph gives me array. maybe i'll try to strip it now `[ [ 'n.name : (' ],
  [ 'n.name : node_name' ],
  [ 'n.name : ;' ],
  [ 'n.name : CREATE' ],
  [ 'n.name : )' ] ]`

Answer (score 0):

result.data.join('') by **jonpacker** https://github.com/brikteknologier/seraph/issues/166